# Python - Replacing letters in a string?

Tags: python

I am basically writing a simple function in which the user enters a sentence (**strng**), a letter (**letter**) and another letter (**replace**) to replace the first letter with. Here's what I have:

```
def letter_replace(strng, letter, replace):
    replace = str(replace)
    for char in strng:
        if char == letter.upper() or char == letter.lower():
            strng.replace(char, replace)
            return strng
        else:
            return "Sorry, the letter could not be replaced."
```

I can't figure out why this won't work. Sorry if it's a completely obvious mistake, I am fairly new to Python.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strings` are immutable, you need to assign it to a new variable and return that. `replace()` returns a new string and does not change it in place.

```
>>> def letter_replace(strng, letter, replace):
    replace = str(replace)
    for char in strng:
        if char == letter.upper() or char == letter.lower():
            strng = strng.replace(char, replace)
            return strng   # Or just do return strng.replace(char, replace)
        else:
            return "Sorry, the letter could not be replaced."


>>> letter_replace('abc', 'a', 'f')
'fbc'
```

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained

Comment: I'm trying, its telling me to wait 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

```
strng.replace(char, replace)
```

This does the replacement, creating a new string, and then *throws away* the changed string because you don't assign it to a variable.

Since you're just going to return it anyway, you can simply write:

```
return strng.replace(char, replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using regex:

```
In [11]: import re

In [12]: def letter_replace(s, l, r):
   ....:     p = re.compile(l, re.IGNORECASE)
   ....:     return p.sub(r, s, 1)
   ....: 

In [13]: letter_replace('AaBbCc', 'a', 'x')
Out[13]: 'xaBbCc'
```

Answer (score 0):

use string translate!!!

```
import string
old_chars = "aeiou"
replace_chars = "!@#$%"
tab = string.maketrans(old_chars,replace_chars)
print "somestring".translate(tab)
```

oh nevermind... I just read you only want to use one character ...

use string.replace ...